# Enable/Disable camera app programmatically

Tags: ios, ios5, camera

Is there a way to programmatically restrict camera access on iPhone 4S 5.0.1?

I am building a simple app with a button to enable/disable shooting with the camera.
I believe it should work in the similar way as the restrictions work in Settings app.
I am not going to deploy it, so I do not mind about Apple's approve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such a policy based programming like android in iphone to disable the camera. its possible only in rooted iphones.

Comment: Thanks.. almost an year after, I almost forgot I did ask it somewhen, but thanks! :)

Comment: Apple says there are some ways to control the enabling and disabling of camera features. Please check this http://images.apple.com/ie/iphone/business/docs/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Comment: I too have a same functionality, how to block the camera app, the above link is not working can you update the new link @BhanuBirani

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option will be with MDM solutions

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what this means ?